# Super Powereds year 3 teachers, disciplines and hero names

Tags: super-powereds

In Drew Hayes [Super Powereds](https://www.drewhayesnovels.com/superpowereds): Year 3 the HCP is attacked and the teachers resume their hero personas in order to fight off the attack.

I'm coming up short on matching the hero names to the teachers and the discipline they are responsible for. (Control, Focus, etc.)

While I think I know most of them I'd like an answer that sets out all of them so that I don't have to ask another question in case I've made one or more incorrect assignments already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my major confusion was caused by thinking there were five potential majors, when there are actually six. The ranged discipline not making a huge impact in the storyline.

Blaine - Dean - Zero
Cole - Weapons - Seamstress
Pendleton - Subtlety - Wisp
Stone - Focus - Emerald Hydra
Hill - Control - Black Hole
Fletcher - Close Combat - Mr. Volt
Baker - Ranged - Impact